# Expresso store: in stock tag inside modifiers options

Tags: expresso-store, stock

I have a code which looks like:

```
{modifier_options}
{if total_stock > 0}
<option value="{option_id}">{option_name} {if price_mod_val} ({price_mod}) [{store_product_stock_level} in stock] {/if}</option>
{/if}
{/modifier_options}
```

which shows total stock (sum) of all options not stock per option.

Also how to display stock amount per product option? So far it shows sum of all product options not X stock amount per product option.

Any clue how to get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Similar question with answer and example here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24103/expresso-store-modifier-stock-levels-availability/24153#24153

Answer (score 1):

The correct code for this is:

```
{modifier_options}{if option_stock_level > 0}{option_name} - {option_stock_level} in stock{if:else}Out of Stock{/if}{/modifier_options}
```

Hope that helps!